# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate on tvOS not being called

Tags: swift, tvos

So I'm trying to do an animated transition between viewcontrollers on tvOS 10.

The UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol is available on tvOS so I assumed I could animate it as well. But for some reason none of the functions are ever called when presenting the new viewcontroller.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong since I'm doing basically the exact same on iOS.

Here is the code I'm using:

---

Presenting code

```
func showStuff() {
    let viewController = ResultViewController()
    viewController.transitioningDelegate = ResultViewControllerTransitionManager()
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

Transition Delegate

```
class ResultViewControllerTransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    var duration = 0.5
    var isPresenting = false

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else {return}
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else {return}

        (...)
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        isPresenting = false
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        isPresenting = true
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently initialising the animationmanager in the `showStuff()` function was the problem. Storing it as a property in the Main viewcontroller and passing it along did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocols inside your first view controller. Your first `UIViewController` may have the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func showStuff() {
        let viewController = ResultViewController()
        viewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    var duration = 0.5
    var isPresenting = false
    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {

        return 2.0
    }
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else {return}
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else {return}

    }
}
```

Also, I present a new controller from the first one (not from the navigationController).

Comment: I prefer to keep the animation methods in a separate class. So I can reuse it in other places and to keep the original viewcontroller more clean.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the issue be that you are using a navigationController, so that navigationController?.delegate needs to equal your ResultViewControllerTransitionManager()?

We have one at work using a push animation (should be the same issue), but we set

`navigationController?.delegate = transitionDelegate`